# Which write permission with ASP.NET and IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net, permissions, write

I have problems setting up the right permissions on my server for writing, modifying content. I simple get a "Access denied" when I try to unpack a zip-file or write some files to the folder using ASP.NET.

What recommendations do you recommend for setting up permissions for ASP.NET (writing files, unpacking files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this is the application pool identity's user that needs write access.  That's Network Service by default for IIS6 and IIS7 (but not IIS7.5)  Check the properties of your app pool and try setting that.

If you have impersonation turned on in ASP.NET then it will be your website's identity (anonymous or authenticated if you use Windows Authentication).

To find out for sure which user is denied permission, run process monitor from [sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com).  It's safe to run on a production server.  After getting a capture while you reproduce the error, search for the word 'denied'.  That will show which user tried to access what.

Comment: Setting the application user to write solves this issue!